# Change HTML elements dynamically by cookie variable

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I have a website and on their I want to change HTML links dynamically based on a cookie variable. This cookie variable is set by PHP. The cookie request is done periodically every minute. Therefore the javascript variable is uptodate. Now I want to check this javascript variable every minute if it changed. Depending on the value of this variable a link should be shown or not. How can I implement such idea in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the variable. If it has the state x, then print the value in the div section.

```
$("#divsection").html("html code goes in here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the setTimeout function to check cookie value every minute -

```
setTimeout(function(){
  if(getCookie(cookie_name) == 'desired_value') {alert ('yes');}
, 60000);


function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
        if (c.indexOf(name) != -1) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
    }
    return "";
}
```